# How many six-digit sequences have exactly three even digits?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

For me its easy to see that for the length two its 50 ( 01, 03, 05, 07, 09, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, ..., 90, 92, 94, 96, 98), but i cannot abstract it 6 digits

Comment: Have you learned anything about combinations?

Comment: For two digits you have two "masks": $OE$ and $EO$, meaning odd-even or even-odd, and then 5 choices of either odd or even digits, $2\times 5 \times 5$. For six digits you have masks like $OOOEEE$, $OOEOEE$, $OEOEOE$,  $EEOEOO$, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The odd numbers can be distributed among the six numbers in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways and for each slot there are $5$ possible odd number choices and for each even number slot $5$ possible even number choices. You are looking for $\binom{6}{3}\cdot(5^3)^2$.